# DGA(Domain Generation Algorithm) based malware files

Tags: malware, networking, dga

Where i can get DGA (Domain Generation Algorithm) based malware files for analysis?
And,Can I get malware family names which is using Domain Generation Algorithm?

Comment: I don't think anyone makes a special category for DGA-based malware so you'll just have to find them yourself among other samples. Otherwise such type of question is too broad to be answered properly.

Comment: I tend to disagree with closing this question. There are only dozens of DGA-centric malware families, and only a handful of well-known ones. This question, IMHO, can be cleanly answered and provides value to users. I therefore nominate it to reopening.

Comment: you can use https://www.botconf.eu/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/OK-P06-Plohmann-DGArchive.pdf is a reasonable start

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know of no collection of malware **samples**, focusing specifically on DGAs.
However, there are some resources that generally concentrate on DGAs and may provide you enough pointers to identify a reasonable number of different samples yourself.

1. There is [Johannes Bader's github repository](https://github.com/baderj/domain_generation_algorithms) which features several reimplementations of DGAs found in malware, along with detailed write-ups and reference hashes.
2. If you are looking for some more background (more than in my BotConf talk) check out our [USENIX paper](https://www.usenix.org/conference/usenixsecurity16/technical-sessions/presentation/plohmann), we listed many of the primary characteristics for a selection DGAs.
3. I also run [DGArchive](https://dgarchive.caad.fkie.fraunhofer.de) - the referenced database of algorithmically generated domains (69 DGAs, 617 seeds, 63,699,402 unique domains). Other similar databases are [John Bambenek's OSINT feed](http://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/feeds/) and [360.cn Netlab's DGA project](http://data.netlab.360.com/dga).
4. I will likely provide tags on samples (such as "c2_dga" or similar) on the corpus of my current pet project [malpedia](http://pnx.tf/slides/2017-03-16-ACSC-Malpedia.pdf).